# Consulta linq para obtener las filas con fecha mas antigua de un conjunto de datos

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, base-de-datos, linq, sql

ID (número autogenerado) 
IDFK (número autogenerado) pero puede repetirse 
FECHA (A DATE) ...

```
 ID IDFK FECHA
 1 1 1/1/1999
 2 1 1/2/1999
 3 2 1/3/1999
 4 3 1/2/1999
 5 4 1/5/1999
 6 4 1/3/1999
 7 1 1/4/1999
```

Ok, piense que el ID mas alto no tiene porque coincidir con la FECHA mas tardia, ya que existen más parámetros que comprueban si la fila es válida para ser tomarlo.

Creo que debo hacer una subconsulta, pero no soy experto en este momento para una consulta tan difícil. Esta es mi razón para pedir ayuda. Por un lado tengo que agrupar por IDFK, y por el otro coger la fecha mas vieja.

Tambien si se puede hacer en dos consultas, acepto esa solución

en este ejemplo los datos validos serian

```
3 2 1/3/1999
4 3 1/2/1999
5 4 1/5/1999
7 1 1/4/1999
```

Gracias

Comment: gracias, por la sugerencia

Comment: eso es en linq? no tiene nada que ver con base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto

```
Dim sortedResult = ClassList.OrderBy(Function(s) s.ID)
                          .ThenBy(Function(s) s.IDFK).ThenBy(Function(s) s.FECHA)
```

De no funcionar entra a http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending un tutorial de LINQ que en mi opinión está muy bueno y con ejemplos tanto en C# como VB.net. Saludos